# Openpyxl - not seeing prices

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am writing a program to search through workbooks for part numbers. If it finds the specified part number, it iterates over that row to find the parts price value that you specify and swaps both out for a replacement value.

However my code is not finding the prices

```
import openpyxl
import os
from datetime import datetime


DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
extentions = (".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".xltx", ".xltm")

target = input("\033[1m\033[96mPart number: \033[0m")
target_replacement = input("\033[1m\033[96mReplace with: \033[0m")

price = input("\033[1m\033[96mPrice: \033[0m")
price_replacement = input("\033[1m\033[96mReplace with: \033[0m")


for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(DIRECTORY):
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith(extentions)):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(
                "\033[1m\033[96mOpening:\033[0m \033[1m\033[93m{0}\033[0m".format(file))
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True)
            ws = wb.active
            target_in_wb = False
            for ws in wb.worksheets:
                for row in ws.iter_rows():
                    target_in_row = False
                    price_in_row = False
                    for cell in row:
                        if (cell.value == target):
                            print("\033[1m\033[92mTARGET STRING FOUND\033[0m")
                            print("\033[1m\033[96mReplacing\033[0m \033[1m\033[93m{0}\033[0m with \033[1m\033[93m{1}\033[0m on row \033[1m\033[93m{2}\033[0m".format(
                                target, target_replacement, ws._current_row))
                            cell.value = target_replacement
                            target_in_wb = True
                            for cell in row:
                                target_in_row = False

                                if (cell.value == price):
                                    print(
                                        "\033[1m\033[92mPRICE STRING FOUND\033[0m")
                                    print("\033[1m\033[96mReplacing\033[0m \033[1m\033[93m{0}\033[0m with \033[1m\033[93m{1}\033[0m on row \033[1m\033[93m{2}\033[0m".format(
                                        price, price_replacement, ws._current_row))
                                    cell.value = price_replacement
                                    price_in_row = True

            if (target_in_row == False):
                print(
                    "\033[1m\033[91mPrice string not found\033[0m")

            if (target_in_wb == False):
                print("\033[1m\033[91mPart not found\033[0m")

                print(
                    "\033[1m\033[96mSaving:\033[0m \033[1m\033[93m{}\033[0m at \033[1m\033[96m{}\033[0m\n".format(file, datetime.now()))
                wb.save(file)

print("\033[95m[\033[0m\033[96m*\033[0m\033[95m]\033[0m \033[1m\033[96mDone\033[0m")
```

Comment: Have you checked that you use the same encoding?

Comment: Can individual cells have their different encoding? It can recognize cells that contain strings of text but it seems that numbers with decimals are not recognized by my code.

Comment: Have you tried testing with a specific case or cell that you know matches? Try to print out the results and compare.

Comment: Yes I did and it was printing out the exact price I'd provide. I got it to work and I'll provide an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing:

```
price = input("\033[1m\033[96mPrice: \033[0m")
price_replacement = input("\033[1m\033[96mReplace with: \033[0m")
```

to:

```
price = float(input("\033[1m\033[96mPrice: \033[0m"))
price_replacement = float(input("\033[1m\033[96mReplace with: \033[0m"))
```

)